# 'wrath for women' vs 'wrath against women'

Tags: prepositions

This is from [*The Washington Post* article](https://www.washingtonpost.com/arts-entertainment/2022/04/10/johnny-depp-amber-heard-case/#O47DR7OJSFGTTDAPJDXIIHQFJI-1).

> Heard urged support for women who come forward as victims of violence,
> and wrote that “two years ago, I became a public figure representing
> domestic abuse, and I felt the full force of our culture’s **wrath for**
> women who speak out. … I had the rare vantage point of seeing, in real
> time, how institutions protect men accused of abuse.” She did not
> mention Depp by name.

I wonder if 'wrath against' can be substituted for 'wrath for' in the above context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It this case, it seems both "culture's wrath for women" and "culture's wrath against women" have the same meaning, as the article refers to Heard felling the full force of the culture's wrath, which probably suggests it's against her.

Comment: But in this sentence 'culture's wrath' seems to be wrath against women. In December 2018, Heard wrote an op-ed that was published in The Post with the headline, “Amber Heard: I spoke up against sexual violence — and faced our culture’s wrath. That has to change.”

Comment: Would you mind explaining what "our culture" refers to? thanks @SEProfile

Comment: @SEProfile I have edited my post. I think it's against after reading more on the article